# compile bootstrap by webpack from sass to css file is too large in laravel 5.4(.css and .map, all in one .css file)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, webpack, laravel-5.4

i compile webpack from sass to css but .map and .css file is **all in one** .css file. so it's too big file. about **650kb**( only bootstrap v4-alpha).

In css folder of bootstrap v4, it's separate.

So, what can i separate it from sass to css by webpack.

here is my webpack congiguration

```js
let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let Mix = require('laravel-mix').config;
let plugins = require('laravel-mix').plugins;


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Initialization
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | As our first step, we'll require the project's Laravel Mix file
 | and record the user's requested compilation and build steps.
 | Once those steps have been recorded, we may get to work.
 |
 */

Mix.initialize();


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Webpack Context
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | This prop will determine the appropriate context, when running Webpack.
 | Since you have the option of publishing this webpack.config.js file
 | to your project root, we will dynamically set the path for you.
 |
 */

module.exports.context = Mix.Paths.root();


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Webpack Entry
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | We'll first specify the entry point for Webpack. By default, we'll
 | assume a single bundled file, but you may call Mix.extract()
 | to make a separate bundle specifically for vendor libraries.
 |
 */

module.exports.entry = Mix.entry();


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Webpack Output
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Webpack naturally requires us to specify our desired output path and
 | file name. We'll simply echo what you passed to with Mix.js().
 | Note that, for Mix.version(), we'll properly hash the file.
 |
 */

module.exports.output = Mix.output();


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Rules
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Webpack rules allow us to register any number of loaders and options.
 | Out of the box, we'll provide a handful to get you up and running
 | as quickly as possible, though feel free to add to this list.
 |
 */

let vueExtractTextPlugin = false;

if (Mix.options.extractVueStyles) {
    vueExtractTextPlugin = Mix.vueExtractTextPlugin();

    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat(vueExtractTextPlugin);
}


module.exports.module = {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                loaders: Mix.options.extractVueStyles ? {
                    js: 'babel-loader' + Mix.babelConfig(),
                    scss: vueExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!sass-loader',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),
                    sass: vueExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),
                    stylus: vueExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader!stylus-loader?paths[]=node_modules',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    }),
                    css: vueExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader',
                        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                    })
                }: {
                    js: 'babel-loader' + Mix.babelConfig(),
                    scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                    sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
                    stylus: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader?paths[]=node_modules'
                },

                postcss: Mix.options.postCss
            }
        },

        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader' + Mix.babelConfig()
        },

        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },

        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
            include: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },

        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loaders: ['html-loader']
        },

        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: 'images/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
                publicPath: Mix.resourceRoot
            }
        },

        {
            test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]',
                publicPath: Mix.resourceRoot
            }
        },

        {
            test: /\.(cur|ani)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
                publicPath: Mix.resourceRoot
            }
        }
    ]
};


if (Mix.preprocessors) {
    Mix.preprocessors.forEach(preprocessor => {
        module.exports.module.rules.push(preprocessor.rules());

        module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat(preprocessor.extractPlugin);
    });
}


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Resolve
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Here, we may set any options/aliases that affect Webpack's resolving
 | of modules. To begin, we will provide the necessary Vue alias to
 | load the Vue common library. You may delete this, if needed.
 |
 */

module.exports.resolve = {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.vue'],

    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
};



/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Stats
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | By default, Webpack spits a lot of information out to the terminal,
 | each you time you compile. Let's keep things a bit more minimal
 | and hide a few of those bits and pieces. Adjust as you wish.
 |
 */

module.exports.stats = {
    hash: false,
    version: false,
    timings: false,
    children: false,
    errors: false
};

process.noDeprecation = true;

module.exports.performance = { hints: false };



/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Devtool
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Sourcemaps allow us to access our original source code within the
 | browser, even if we're serving a bundled script or stylesheet.
 | You may activate sourcemaps, by adding Mix.sourceMaps().
 |
 */

module.exports.devtool = Mix.sourcemaps;



/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Webpack Dev Server Configuration
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | If you want to use that flashy hot module replacement feature, then
 | we've got you covered. Here, we'll set some basic initial config
 | for the Node server. You very likely won't want to edit this.
 |
 */
module.exports.devServer = {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    compress: true,
    quiet: true
};



/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Plugins
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Lastly, we'll register a number of plugins to extend and configure
 | Webpack. To get you started, we've included a handful of useful
 | extensions, for versioning, OS notifications, and much more.
 |
 */

module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(Mix.autoload || {
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }),

    new plugins.FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),

    new plugins.StatsWriterPlugin({
        filename: 'mix-manifest.json',
        transform: Mix.manifest.transform.bind(Mix.manifest),
    }),

    new plugins.WebpackMd5HashPlugin(),

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: Mix.inProduction,
        options: {
            postcss: Mix.options.postCss,
            context: __dirname,
            output: { path: './' }
        }
    })
]);


if (Mix.browserSync) {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new plugins.BrowserSyncPlugin(
            Object.assign({
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
                proxy: 'app.dev',
                files: [
                    'app/**/*.php',
                    'resources/views/**/*.php',
                    'public/js/**/*.js',
                    'public/css/**/*.css'
                ]
            }, Mix.browserSync),
            {
                reload: false
            }
        )
    );
}


if (Mix.notifications) {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new plugins.WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'Laravel Mix',
            alwaysNotify: true,
            contentImage: Mix.Paths.root('node_modules/laravel-mix/icons/laravel.png')
        })
    );
}


if (Mix.copy) {
    Mix.copy.forEach(copy => {
        module.exports.plugins.push(
            new plugins.CopyWebpackPlugin([copy])
        );
    });
}


if (Mix.extract) {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: Mix.entryBuilder.extractions.concat([
                path.join(Mix.js.base, 'manifest').replace(/\\/g, '/')
            ]),
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    );
}


if (Mix.inProduction) {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(Mix.options.uglify)
    );
}


module.exports.plugins.push(
    new plugins.WebpackOnBuildPlugin(
        stats => Mix.events.fire('build', stats)
    )
);


/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Finalizing
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Now that we've declared the entirety of our Webpack configuration, the
 | final step is to scan for any custom configuration in the Mix file.
 | If mix.webpackConfig() is called, we'll merge it in, and build!
 |
 */
Mix.finalize(module.exports);
```

Comment: Show your webpack configuration.

Comment: i have updated my answer above -@wuxiandiejia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `module.exports.devtool = Mix.sourcemaps;` to `module.exports.devtool='#source-map'`.

I found the `laravel-mix` set `devtool` to `#inline-source-map`.

ps: `inline-source-map` - A SourceMap is added as DataUrl to the JavaScript file.

Comment: wow. It's work:D. the css bootstrap file is only 180kb. Thanks